# Delphi XE5 Upd1 ShowMessage generate AV

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have updated several of my application for XE5 Update1. Since then, ShowMessage frequently triggers an access violation. This happens in several application without apparent reason. If I replace ShowMessage by a simple form, then the AV is gone. So this is clearly ShowMessage which is the culprit.

The AV occurs in WinApi.CommCtrl.pas in function TaskDialogIndirect (See marked line below):

```
function TaskDialogIndirect(const pTaskConfig: TTaskDialogConfig;
  pnButton: PInteger; pnRadioButton: PInteger; pfVerificationFlagChecked: PBOOL): HRESULT;
begin
  if Assigned(_TaskDialogIndirect) then
    Result := _TaskDialogIndirect(pTaskConfig, pnButton, pnRadioButton,
      pfVerificationFlagChecked)         // <====== HERE ==========
  else
  begin
    InitComCtl;
    Result := E_NOTIMPL;
    if ComCtl32DLL <> 0 then
    begin
      @_TaskDialogIndirect := GetProcAddress(ComCtl32DLL, 'TaskDialogIndirect');
      if Assigned(_TaskDialogIndirect) then
        Result := _TaskDialogIndirect(pTaskConfig, pnButton, pnRadioButton,
          pfVerificationFlagChecked)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The stack trace when the exception occurs:

```
:671cab85 ; D:\Development\DelphiLibs\madCollection\madExcept\Dlls\madExcept32.dll
:671cabe2 ; D:\Development\DelphiLibs\madCollection\madExcept\Dlls\madExcept32.dll
:671ca755 madExcept32.ThisIsNoLeak + 0x29
:004aa9d7 ThisIsNoLeak + $F
:004a9412 HookedCreateThread + $82
:769613a2 msvcrt._beginthreadex + 0x74
:5f028473 ; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DUser.dll
:5f028234 DUser.InitGadgets + 0xf5
:5f028177 DUser.InitGadgets + 0x38
:70e4da8d ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
:70e5d492 ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
Winapi.CommCtrl.TaskDialogIndirect(???,???,$18E974,$18E96C)
Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog.DoExecute(460578)
Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog.Execute(???)
Vcl.Dialogs.TTaskMessageDialog.Execute(???)
Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog.Execute
Vcl.Dialogs.DoTaskMessageDlgPosHelp('','Calibration failed Unknown error',mtCustom,[mbOK],0,-1,-1,'',mbOK)
Vcl.Dialogs.DoTaskMessageDlgPosHelp('',???,mtCustom,[mbOK],0,-1,-1,'')
Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlgPosHelp('Calibration failed Unknown error',mtCustom,[mbOK],0,-1,-1,'')
Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessagePos('',-1,-1)
Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessage(???)
AutomationTechspCalibration.TCalibrationForm.StartCalibrationButtonClick($8C56D14)
Vcl.Controls.TControl.Click
Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Click
Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.CNCommand(???)
Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc((48401, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc((48401, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.StdCtrls.TButtonControl.WndProc((48401, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform(???,???,526074)
Vcl.Controls.DoControlMsg(???,(no value))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WMCommand((273, (), 1786, 0, (), 526074, 0))
Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WMCommand((273, (), 1786, 0, (), 526074, 0))
Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc((273, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc((273, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc((273, 1786, 526074, 0, 1786, 0, (), 1786, 8, (), 0, 0, ()))
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc(???)
System.Classes.StdWndProc(460578,273,1786,526074)
:757462fa ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:75746d3a USER32.GetThreadDesktop + 0xd7
:7574965e ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:757496c5 USER32.SendMessageW + 0x4c
:70e84601 ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
:70e84663 ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
:70e844ed ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
:757462fa ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:75746d3a USER32.GetThreadDesktop + 0xd7
:75750d27 USER32.GetClientRect + 0xc5
:75750d4d USER32.CallWindowProcW + 0x1b
Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler(???)
:005b92ef TWinControl.DefaultHandler + $EB
:005b91de TWinControl.WndProc + $5CA
:005d6599 TButtonControl.WndProc + $71
:0053ea12 StdWndProc + $16
:757462fa ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:75746d3a USER32.GetThreadDesktop + 0xd7
:757477c4 ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:7574788a USER32.DispatchMessageW + 0xf
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In which platform does the AV appear (Windows,iOS,Android) ?

Comment: @S.MAHDI The stack trace is chock full of VCL units which means this is VCL which means this is Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have disabled madExcept and used FastMM4 (Not the one included with XE5 but the latest version from Sourceforge). FastMM immediately showed me a buffer overflow that madExcept had not caught.

I fixed the issue. I worked a few hours with FastMM, then I used madExcept again and everything works. No more AV.

My conclusion is that the buffer overflow corrupted the heap in a way that led to the ShowMessage AV! madExcept was not the problem, ShowMessage neither. That was my own code (Buffer overflow) which screwed everything. Thanks to FastMM for pointing it almost immediately (Turning on FullDebugMode of FastMM).